# Synonym [wowjs] → [wow.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Can somebody mark [wowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wowjs) (has 18 questions at this moment) a synonym of [wow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wow.js) (70 questions)?

Comment: I think the 18 questions should be re-tagged [tag:wow.js], and then the [tag:wowjs] will be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, [wowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wowjs) is not necessary as it provides no added value over [wow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wow.js). I re-tagged so now [wow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wow.js) contains *all* of the related questions. The [wowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wowjs) tag should be removed by the system soon.